# Smithing Enchant Not Working?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have Smithing to level 100, but only up to Arcane in perks. I have four pieces of +25% smithing enchanted gear.

I noticed sometimes the enchant doesn't show up so I have to re-equip and then it appears under active effects. While wearing all four pieces I could only improve a daedric bow to 51 damage. This seemed off to me, so as an experiment I took off one of the +25% smithing items and tried improving a iron dagger.

To my disappointment I noticed not wearing one of the enchanted pieces resulted in the same improvement. Anyone else having this issue and know how to get around it? If no one has advice I guess I could enchant four more items, but I'd rather not.

Comment: It is working properly, but not having the right perks for smithing will penalize your attempt at improving an item, you need daedric smithing for a daedric bow to fully improve it.

Comment: I was wondering about that, thanks for the reply. Still shouldn't there be a difference between 75% smithing improve bonus and 100%? Also, I had this very notion in the back of my head when I tested on the iron dagger. Iron dagger was improved from 8 damage to 29 with 100% smithing enchants. Iron dagger was improved 8 to 29 with 75% as well.

Comment: @R3DCL0UD Without the necessary perk you simply won't be able to improve items above a certain quality (Flawless, I think), which also limits the maximum damage it can do.

Comment: @Alex You can actually go beyond that with enough of a push, but the gaps between the different ranges -are- significant, especially so with out the Perk for that type of smithing. When you do **not** have the park, you HALF your skill when upgrading items.

Comment: I guess because there is no skill perk for iron smithing using iron dagger as a test subject was unwise. I just tested using a steel dagger (of which I have the perk) and the improvement was as intended. On a separate note, enchanting and smithing for stealthy types just doesn't seem worth while as the gear in the world is pretty cool. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: This also could be a bug, Im experiencing this now. The key to the whole thing is your active effects list, if the enchantment does not show up on the list, then it is not being used. I am currently undergoing an investigation to find a fix for this but am unsuccessful so far
If anyone has any accurate knowledge on the subject it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like your game is working correctly.

**Experiment:**

I just tried your `Iron Dagger` experiment and saw similar results.  The problem is that the `Iron Dagger` base numbers are so small a 25% difference was within 1 damage point.  I tried the same experiment on an `Ebony Sword` (for which I do *not* have the Ebony Smithing perk) and I saw a difference of 5 damage points from the extra +25% Smithing gear.

**Solution:**

If you really want to improve that `Daedric Bow`, you need the Daedric Smithing perk.  Or... you know, a game-breaking level of +Smithing gear/potions.